# How to impersonate Alice = A in this protocol based on replaying a compromised session key

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis

```
the protocol given in past exam paper:
(1) A → S : A, B, Na
(2) S → B : {A, B, Na,Kab}Kas, {A, B, Na,Kab}Kbs
(3) B → A : {A, B, Na,Kab}Kas, {Na}Kab, Nb
(4) A → B : {Nb}Kab
```

my answer when replaying the compromised session key to impersonate A:

```
(1)A -> S : A, B, Na
(2)S -> B : {A, B, Na, Kab}Kas, {A, B, Na, Kab}Kbs // comment assume Kab is compromised
(3)I(S) -> B : {A, B, Na, Kab}Kas, {A, B, Na, Kab}Kbs
(4)B -> I(A) : {A, B, Na, Kab}Kas, {Na}Kab, N’b
(5)I(A) -> B : {N’b}Kab
```

Comment: What is your question? Whether or not you got it right?

Comment: @mikeazo is the answer right or wrong?

Comment: So you are impersonating the server and A?

Comment: A is alice, B is Bob and S is the session key. I am replaying the compromised key so assume line 2 is compromised by secret key Kab.

Comment: line 3 is the replayed session key with intruder S impersonate B

Comment: line 4 B impersonates the intruder key B

Comment: line 5 shows that intruder A impersonates B

Comment: the question Is impersonate A through replaying the session key: Assume S is the session key @mikeazo

Comment: What does the I(A) and the I(S) mean? The impersonator of A and S? So your attack says that in order to impersonate Alice, you must also impersonate the server?